# Grouping by Week in click house database

Tags: sql, clickhouse

How can i group by week in clickhouse query , I'm able to group by month and date by formatDateTime but week is not working.

```
select formatDateTime(added_on,'%d-%m-%y') as "date", 
count(id) as "Count of transactions"
from transaction 
where created_at >= '2022-12-01 00:00:00'
group by 1 
order by 1
```

Comment: `select toStartOfWeek(added_on) AS "date"  ... `

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the date time functions available [here](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/date-time-functions/)

As pointed out by https://stackoverflow.com/users/1204665/slach the [toStartOfWeek](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/date-time-functions/#tostartofweektmode) function is probably what you're after.

You also have

- [toYearWeek](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/date-time-functions/#toyearweekdatemode)
- [toWeek](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/date-time-functions/#toweekdatemode)

depending on your exact requirements.